# SQL Server - string separation with length cutoff

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

So I have a string that is from search and it can contain multiple words I want to cutoff the words at 10 characters i.e.

```
DECLARE @SearchString varchar(255) = 'Administration Duplication'
```

becomes: `'Administra Duplicatio'`

Comment: that is not even a valid syntax

Comment: sorry typed without testing: Declare @SearchString Varchar(255)  = 'Administration Duplication'

Comment: What are you trying to actually achieve?

Comment: i think he needs to split the strings with whitespace; cut the first 10 chars and rejoin the string.

Comment: well ,at first the declare is wrong

Comment: @SnakeFoot it may be wrong is sqlserver 2005 or older. But 2008 and after, this declare syntax and value assignment is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://raresql.com/2013/04/12/sql-server-get-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-column/) with few modifications:

```
Create Function dbo.[getFirstTenCharacters]
(
   @String Varchar(Max) 
)
RETURNS Varchar(Max)
BEGIN
Declare @Xml Xml
Declare @firsttenletter Varchar(Max)
Declare @delimiter Varchar(5)

SET @delimiter=' '
SET @Xml = cast(('<a>'+replace(@String,@delimiter,'</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML)

;With CTE AS (SELECT A.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as [Column]
FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(a) )
SELECT @firsttenletter =Stuff((SELECT ' ' + LEFT([Column],10)
FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH('') ),1,0,'')

RETURN (@firsttenletter)
END
GO


SELECT dbo.[getFirstTenCharacters]('Administration Duplication');
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/6095)**

[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me got this, Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "A" or the user-defined function or aggregate "A.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: @GregWhite:- Are you sure, you used the same code. It worked for me. Added the image as well!

Comment: @GregWhite:- I have attached the working Demo as well. You can check that :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac9aa/1

Comment: thanks this is working in fiddler but not on sql 2012, for some reason i get an error. I will look into it my side but this looks like the solution for me. thank you

Comment: @GregWhite:- You are welcome. I checked on 2008 and 2014 version which I have on my machine and it worked there. Sorry that I cant check on 2012

Comment: My guess is that @GregWhite has a case sensitive SQL instance but Rahul's is case insensitive. Try changing `A.value` to `a.value`?

Answer (score 2):

A rather simpler version would look something like.....

```
DECLARE @SearchString Varchar(255) = 'Administration Duplication'


;WITH X AS (
        SELECT  Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') Words
        FROM   
            (SELECT Cast ('<X>' + 
               Replace(@SearchString, ' ', '</X><X>') + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
            ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
    ) 
SELECT  STUFF((SELECT  ' ' +  Words
               FROM X 
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
              .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to split the strings.
should look something like this:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[SPLIT_STRING](
 @TEXT      varchar(8000)
,@COLUMN    int
,@SEPARATOR varchar(1)
)RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
  BEGIN
       DECLARE @POS_START  int = 1
       DECLARE @POS_END    int = CHARINDEX(@SEPARATOR, @TEXT, @POS_START)

       WHILE (@COLUMN >1 AND @POS_END> 0)
         BEGIN
             SET @POS_START = @POS_END + 1
             SET @POS_END = CHARINDEX(@SEPARATOR, @TEXT, @POS_START)
             SET @COLUMN = @COLUMN - 1
         END 

       IF @COLUMN > 1  SET @POS_START = LEN(@TEXT) + 1
       IF @POS_END = 0 SET @POS_END = LEN(@TEXT) + 1 

       RETURN SUBSTRING (@TEXT, @POS_START, @POS_END - @POS_START)
  END
```

THEN DO:

```
SELECT LEFT([dbo].[SPLIT_STRING](COLNAME,1,' '),10)+LEFT([dbo].[SPLIT_STRING](COLNAME,2,' '),10)
```

Comment: problem I have is that it will contain a unknown number of strings, but I like this.

Comment: first parameter is the column,second is the first part before white space, third the char

Comment: in a while loop with the number of white spaces this works like charm